# Sed not working in usual way - Shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, ubuntu-14.04

I have two `sed` command which includes in my `cook.sh` script. One command is

```
sed -E -i "s/^(\\\$mainDomain=\")[^\"]+(\";)$/\1$MainDomain\2/" /var/config.php
```

This is working fine.

But the below command which is almost same. But it is not working.

```
sed -E -i "s/^(\\\$authURI=\")[^\"]+(\";)$/\1$duo_auth\2/" /var/config.php
```

That give the below error message

> sed: -e expression #1, char 36: unknown option to `s'

Any idea on this ?

Comment: Provide the sample file on which the 2nd command was not working, seems OK and the value of variable `$duo_auth`

Comment: It's probably `$duo_auth` that contains an unescaped `/`. Why do you use `-i`? If you're testing things, it's a sure way of screwing up.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks for the facts. Can u give me a sollution for this ? 
With a sample example. I am totally new for this sed commands.

Comment: What's the value of the sed command after the variables are evaluated? Depending on what the variables are set to all of these strings could be valid or invalid commands.

Comment: Thanks All. Below answer which posted by @Inian worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely due to your replacement variable `$duo_auth` having a un-escaped `/`, change the default `sed` separator from `/` to `~` as

```
sed -E -i "s~^(\\\$authURI=\")[^\"]+(\";)$~\1$duo_auth\2~" /var/config.php
```

Try it without `-i` for seeing if the replacement is as expected and put it back after confirmation.

Example:-

```
cat /var/config.php
<?php
$authURI="dev.digin.io";
```

now setting the variable

```
duo_auth="http://auth.uri.digin.io:3048/"
```

Now the replacement, without `-i`

```
sed -E "s~^(\\\$authURI=\")[^\"]+(\";)$~\1$duo_auth\2~" /var/config.php
<?php
$authURI="http://auth.uri.digin.io:3048/";
```

Comment: Working perfect! Thanks @Inian

Answer (score 0):

The problem is *probably* due to `$duo_auth` containing an unescaped `/`.  This means that the `sed` editing script will have a syntax error.

You may pick any other character to use as a delimiter in the `s/.../.../` command, for example `#`:

```
sed "s#....#....#"
```

Just make sure that you pick a character that is not ever going to turn up in either `$duo_auth` or `$authURI`.

While testing, I'd recommend that you avoid using in-place-editing (`-i`) with `sed`. Also, the `-i` switch is horribly non-portable between `sed` implementations (some requires an argument).

Instead, do the slightly more cumbersome

```
sed -e "s#...#...#" data.in >data.in.tmp && mv -f data.in.tmp data.in
```

While testing, check the `data.in.tmp` file before moving it.

Comment: For some reason `@` de-limiter is causing the same error, revered to `~` seems fine, and `@` is not a meta-character too! strange!

Comment: @Inian Does `$duo_auth` contain a `@` by any chance? If so, yes, it would fail in the same way.

Comment: Nope, tested it even without it.

Comment: @Inian There's the `$authURI` variable too to be aware of. That can't contain the delimiter either.